# How do I preserve the elements of a dictionary with each successive function call?

Tags: python, list, function, python-3.x, dictionary

To clarify, i'm reading from a file and sending each line to a function(1) where it's relevant elements are put into a list. That list is then sent to another function(2) and added to a dictionary, with one element of that list being a key, and the other(s) put inside another list, being the value. So, basically {key:(value(,value)).

Problem is, whenever I send the list from (1) to (2), the newly created dictionary is overwritten. I'm new to Python, but i'm pretty sure I can add multiple keys and values to one dictionary right? So, is there a way to save the elements of the dictionary each time (2) is called? So, if it's called once, it has tokens(a) in the dictionary. When it's called again, it still has tokens(a), and now tokens(b) is added, and so forth.

If you need code I can include it.

MCVE:

```
def file_stuff(file name):
    #opens and reads file using with x open as thing....then
    for line in thing:
       function1(line)


def function1(line):
    #Breaks down line using regex; variable name var for this example
    #list the relevant components of the line will go into 
    element = list()

    for x in var:
       list.append(x)

    function2(element)


def function2(element):
    #Another list is made along with a dictionary
    webster = dict()
    values = list()

    for x in range(len(element)):
        #inserts into dictionary.....the problem being, however, that I need this dictionary to "remember" what was already stored inside
```

Comment: Try to create [mcve](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which explains your issue and post it here. Help us help you...

Comment: Is the psuedocode I provided enough?

Answer (score 1):

In your current code, `webster` is a local variable in `function2` that gets bound to a dictionary. However, you never `return` or do anything else with the dictionary that would allow code outside that function to see it, so when the function ends, there are no further references to the dictionary and it will be garbage collected.

If you want each call to `function2` to use the same dictionary, you need to change the function so that it accesses the dictionary differently. Exactly what way is best will depend on the larger design of your program.

One option would be to make `webster` a global variable, which `function2` can modify in place. This is very easy to do, but it has some pretty severe limitations, since a module has just the one global namespace. Working with multiple files that should have their data put into multiple different dictionaries would be very tough.

It would look something like this:

```
webster = {}

def function2(element):
    ...
    webster[some_key] = some_value
```

Another option would be to make the dictionary an argument to the function, so that the calling code is responsible for creating and holding a reference to it in between calls. This is probably a better approach than using a global variable, but it's harder for me to demonstrate since it's not really clear to me where the dictionary should live in your example (maybe in `function1`, or maybe it needs to be passed all the way through from `file_stuff`).

It might look something like:

```
def caller():
    the_dict = {}

    for item in some_sequence():
        function2(item, the_dict)

def function2(item, webster)
    ...
    webster[some_key] = some_value
```

A final option would be to have `function2` still be in charge of creating the dictionary, but for it to `return` the dictionary to its caller, who could do something with it (such as merging its contents with the dictionaries from previous calls). I'm not even going to attempt to demonstrate this one, since the merging process would depend a lot on what exactly you're putting in your dictionary. (A related option would be to return some other non-dictionary value (or a tuple of values) which could then be inserted in a dictionary by the calling code. This might be easier than dealing with an intermediate dictionary in some situations.)

Comment: Very well explained.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive response. I'll give it all a shot